# Google form answers search in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is it possible to create a Google Form thats asks for surname e idnumber, then search those values into a google sheet and, if a value with that surname and idnumber is found, respond with a positive response or negative if not found?

Comment: How would the response be handled? Would it be a small modal pop up message within Google Sheets or do you have any other ideas in mind?

Comment: it is not possible to "gather" any answers to a form until it is "submitted"

Comment: @CenturyTuna i was thinking about sending an email with the response to the user who compiled and subbitted the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var responseSh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); //get the sheet Form Responses 1 on the linked sheet of your Google Forms
  var dataSh = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //data of surnames and ID's in the same sheet 
  var responses = responseSh.getRange(responseSh.getLastRow() ,2, 1, 3).getValues().flat();
  var data = dataSh.getRange(2,1, dataSh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues(); 
  data.map(x => responses[0] == x[0] && responses[1] == x[1] ? MailApp.sendEmail(responses[2],"Test Subject","Hello World"): x); 
  
}
```

What this does is `var responses = responseSh.getRange(responseSh.getLastRow() ,2, 1, 3).getValues().flat();` gets the last response under the Form Responses 1 sheet.

And then this line of code `data.map(x =\> responses[0] == x[0] && responses[1] == x[1] ? MailApp.sendEmail(responses[2],"Test Subject","Hello World"): x);`  evaluates if the response already contains the Surname and ID within the data.

**Sample data:**

[image]

**Sample Form:**

[image]

Make sure this is set

[image]

And also set this function on Form Submit under Triggers in App Script:

[image]

Here is a sample email I received when I submitted the form:

[image]

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)